# NullPointerException using runOnUiThread()

Tags: java, android

So am trying to use `runOnUiThread()` to update my LogUI (found in my apps MainActivity) which is a TextView. The issue is am trying to update the TextView using `runOnUiThread()` from another class by getting the strings to be made on the View.
Here is details of my code to elaborate my issue:

```
private LoggingClass getLogs;

getLogs.AddtoLogUI(String.format("Established on port: %d", obj));
```

Then the LoggingClass code:

```
public class LoggingClass {

private MainActivity updateUI;
private String stringValue;

public void AddtoLogUI(final String format) {
    this.stringValue = format;
    updateUI.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainActivity.log_this(stringValue);
        }

    });
}
}
```

The method `MainActivity.log_this()` code is like this:

```
public static void log_this(final String msg){

    if(editable.toString().split("\n").length >=50) {
        editable.delete(0, editable.toString().indexOf("\n"));
    }

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            editable.append(msg);
            editable.append("\n");
        }
    };

    LogView.post(runnable);
}
```

PS: LogView is a TextView.

The NullpointerException is thrown when am trying to get the Strings using the `getLogs.AddtoLogUI()` method. 
Any suggestions?

**Additional Info** as regards the object:

```
`Object obj[] = new Object[1];
    obj[0] = Integer.valueOf(Port);`
```

Comment: You can't  not create Activity object. Put more source code.

Comment: What you want to achieve by doing this? i think we should need to restructure your logic to achieve desired results

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace or some more code.

Comment: Have added more codes. What am trying to achieve is getting specific strings to the TextView in my apps MainActivity. This requires me calling a global method to get this Stings from different classes.

Answer (score 1):

You declare `private LoggingClass getLogs;` in your `Activity`
`getLogs=new LoggingClass (MainActivity.this)` in your `onCreate`

then u can use `getLogs.AddtoLogUI(String.format("Established on port: %d", obj));`

create`LoggingClass` constructor

```
public class LoggingClass {

private MainActivity updateUI;
private String stringValue;


public LoggingClass (MainActivity updateUI){
this.updateUI=updateUI;
}


public void AddtoLogUI(final String format) {
    this.stringValue = format;
    updateUI.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainActivity.log_this(stringValue);
        }

    });
}
}
```

Comment: I couldn't initialize the loggingclass like you stated as the class am trying to do that implements a runnable. What am trying to achieve is getting the different strings to the TextView in the MainActivity using a global method called from different classes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue myself using a handler instead. Here is a sample code of what I did:

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
          // UI code goes here
     }
});
```